# Removing Blank Lines At The Beginning of a File C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a document that has several blank lines in the beginning.  I am trying to remove the empty lines from the beginning of a document only.  I have this code that removes blank lines from the entire document but I just want to remove the blank lines at the beginning.  Typically, there are 1-4 blank lines prior to the information I need.

```
   var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Where(arg => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg));
   File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
```

I have considered using a while loop using while readline(fileName).First.Length = 0 but I'm worried that I might have to read and write very large files several times before I get the file I need (i.e. one without blank lines in the beginning).

I do want to get rid of line breaks.

Comment: I think you need to negate your condition.

Comment: When you say blank lines I assume you mean remove white spaces and empty characters? Not full line breaks

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification and you are right - my condition should be negated.  I will edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines.SkipWhile(line => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)));
```

Comment: While this is fairly self explanatory, a brief description of the code would bring this into line with answer standards :) We see these in the review queue